# Is it possible to define a foreign key with duplication and cascading delete only if no values exist?

Tags: database-design, mariadb, foreign-key

I have the following scenario:

A survey table with the columns `survey_type` and `survey_version`.
`(survey_type, survey_version)` is a primary key of the survey table.

I also have a request table. It contains `requestIDs` that are associated with a survey_type. Whenever a user initiates a survey for a certain `requestID`, they will get the most up to date `survey_version`.

I wish to enforce the restriction that allows creation of requests only for survey_types that actually exist. I also wish for requests to be deleted if the associated `request_type` is removed from the system. A `FOREIGN KEY` with `ON DELETE CASCADE` is almost a perfect solution, except that I need the cascading to happen only if all records with a certain `survey_type` are removed. If we are only removing an old and no longer used version of a `survey_type`, but records of that `survey_type` still exist in the survey table, then the survey request should also remain in the system.

Is this possible to do with `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, or should I look for another way?

Comment: Speak SQL, show the CREATE TABLE commands for all the available tables -- show up your schema. Where does `request_type` come in?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MariaDB.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is this possible to do with FOREIGN KEY constraints, or should I look for another way?

Look another way. I'm not 100% I understand what's happening from that description but `ON DELETE CASCADE` quite explicitly means *"allow the deletion to cascade"*. There are no buts about it.

Or, just make sure in the app, you check -- in a transaction -- that there are no remaining `survey_type`'s then you can delete and allow it to cascade naturally.